# How to pass objects around routes in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Lets say I have 3 routes nested inside each other:

```
/users - shows UserList
  - /:id - shows UserDetail
     - /address - shows the 'Address' tab of a 'user' object
```

In this case, the `/address` route needs the `user` object that `/:id` route has.

It doesnt need to fetch it from the server since the `/:id` route already fetched it.  It just needs the pointer to that object.

How do i pass the object obtained by `/:id` to `/address` route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [modelFor](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor) method on your route. For instance, your `address` route could look like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params, transition) {
        return this.findModel('address', params.address_id);
    }

    setupController(controller, model) {
        controller.set('address', model);
        controller.set('user', this.modelFor('users.id'));
    }
});
```

Now instead of just a `model` property, your controller now has access to `address` and `user` properties.

Comment: where is the `findModel` method defined and what does it do?

Comment: It's just a [shortcut defined on the route](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_findModel). That call is equivalent to `this.store.find('address', params.address_id)`.